# Getting next valid date from Android Calendar

Tags: java, android, validation, date

I'm trying to get sequence of date for an Android app. The quest is to traverse from one date to n days after. but I need to validate if the date + 1 day is a valid date. ie, if my starting date is 02-28-2014, is there an method from some Interface that gets automatically the next valid date? I know that I can build a mechanism to do this validation, I was just wondering if exists some integrated method on the Android API or the Java API.

I have three class properties which I set like this:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
this.mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
this.mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
this.mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

since you are already using Calendar, I use this:

```
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, number_of_days_to_add);
```

Your Calendar will then be set and you can request the date using `new Date(c.getTime())`